# WPF nested itemscontrol EventToCommand binding path error

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, nested, itemscontrol

I have a problem with my WPF bindings inside an itemscontrol. The following error occurs

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MovieImageClick' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=56697999)'. BindingExpression:Path=MovieImageClick; DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=56697999); target element is 'EventToCommand' (HashCode=42916613); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

A simple example of the XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="movie_poster_grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=AllMovies}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Image Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="200" Height="300">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                  <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MovieImageClick , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
               </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
         </Image>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have a MVVM framework and connect the datacontext on the following way to a ModernUserControl:

```
DataContext="{Binding MovieListModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Inside this viewmodel is a Relaycommand MovieImageClick i wish to connect the trigger to.

Situation:
If i put the trigger directly inside the itemscontrol it will work! If i put the trigger deeper inside the itemscontrol it does not work. So I think the problem is with finding the viewmodel throughout the itemscontrol. The weird thing is that the trigger can find the itemscontrol but cannot find the command or something. Please help me out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are binding to the ItemsControl but you want the DataContext of the ItemsControl. Try this:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MovieImageClick, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
```